# Mongodb connection not working

Tags: php, mongodb

Hi, I am experiencing several problems with this. Please help me!

My code looks like this:

```
session_start(); $GLOBALS["config"] =array( "mongodb"=> array( "host"=> "127.0.0.1","username"=>"root", "password"=>"","db"=>"lr"),"remember"=> array( "cookie_name"=>"shoeib", "cookie_expire"=> 604800 ),
"session"=> array( "session_name"=>"users") );
spl_autoload_register(function($class) { require_once"classes/" . $class.".php"; }); require_once "functions/sanitize.php";
```

this is the database where i created db only!

```
class db{



private static $_instance= null;
private $_pdo,
$_query,
$_error= FALSE,
$_result,
$_count= 0;

public function __construct(){ try { $this->$connection = new Mongoclient("mongoclient:host".config::get ("mongodb/host").";dbname=".config::get("mongodb/db"),config::get("mongodb/username"),config::get ("mongodb/password"));$this->database = $this->connection-> selectDB(DBConnection::DBNAME);} catch (MongoConnectionException $e)throw $e; } }public static function getInstance(){ if (!isset(self::$instance)) { self::$instance = new db;} return self::$instance;}
```

public function getCollection($name) {return $this->database->selectCollection($name);}

Comment: Please format your code to make it more readable. Also -- it's not clear what you're question is? Is MongoDB running? Many forget to actually start the service/daemon/process if they haven't used it before.

Comment: You didn't address the formatting issues, or clarify what your question is. Is MongoDB running?

Comment: i am trying to build mongodb connection on one page to connect all my pages basically i want one mongodb page!

Comment: no mongodb can run only at my university it doesn't have access to outside i just want to build one connection to make all my php work thats because i have my own username and password for mongodb swell but can only access it at university rules not inside

Answer (score 0):

You ended your db class on wrong line, try this

```
class db
{

    private static $_instance = null;
    private $_pdo,
        $_query,
        $_error = FALSE,
        $_result,
        $_count = 0;

    public function __construct()
    {
        try {
            $this->$connection = new Mongoclient("mongoclient:host" . config::get("mongodb/host") . ";dbname=" . config::get("mongodb/db"), config::get("mongodb/username"), config::get("mongodb/password"));
            $this->database = $this->connection->selectDB(DBConnection::DBNAME);
        } catch (MongoConnectionException $e)throw $e;
    }

    public static function getInstance()
    {
        if (!isset(self::$instance)) {
            self::$instance = new db;
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }
    public function getCollection($name)
    {
        return $this->database->selectCollection($name);
    }
}
```

Your MongoClient usage seems incorrect, but I might be wrong [PHP.net MongoClient](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongoclient.construct.php)

```
public MongoClient::__construct() ([ string $server = "mongodb://localhost:27017" [, array $options = array("connect" => TRUE) ]] )
```

Also take a look at [this tutorial](http://www.tutstub.com/mongodb-php-tutorial/)